# Marketing Data Sharing option for Pardot Connector is NOT available even after upgrading the connector to v2

Tags: pardot

Marketing Data Sharing option for Pardot Connector is NOT available even after upgrading the connector to v2?

I have requirement to sync contacts with particular record type. Marketing data sharing is a setting to do but I can't see that option in my Connectors setting.

Can anyone please help? Below are some details regarding the connector

- Pardot Plus Edition we are using
- Using Connector user with object permissions

Answer (score 0):

Marketing Data Sharing is only accessible with the Pardot Premium and Advanced editions.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_sf_connector_setup_selective_sync_parent.htm&type=5